# Gulp + Browserify + TypeScript To Browser

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp, browserify

My problem is the following:

I use gulp+browserify to compile my TypeScript to JavaScript that you can use on normal HTML pages, the problem is that my class is never available on the browser:

```
VM633:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Test is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

This is my TypeScript File:

```html
class Test {
        public test(): void {
            console.log("aa");
        }
}
```

This is my gulpfile

```html
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var tsify = require("tsify");

gulp.task("default", function () {
    return browserify({
        //basedir: '.',
        debug: true,
        entries: ['app/Resources/typescript/Test.ts'],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
        .plugin(tsify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("web/bundles/framework/js"));
});
```

The file compiles without problem, and is included in my index.html (the compiled js file).

But when i try:

```html
 var t = new Test();
```

I get the following error:

```
VM633:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Test is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

I can't resolve it, I have read a lot and I haven't found anything clear, I tried all and nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things missing here:

If you want your class to be accessible outside of your module, you have to `export` it:

```
export class Test {
    // ...
}
```

Browserify creates functions on top of the classes you define. So it won't be accessible globally (which is a good thing). Normally you would import it in another file and use it:

```
// in any TS file that wants to use `Test` class. Make sure this is included in the gulp entries as well
import {Test} from "test";
var t = new Test();
console.log(t);
```

Or if really want it to be accessible globally, you can attach it to `window` object:

// In Test.ts file:

```
(window as any).Test = Test; // This can be useful when debuging. But don't do this in production code.
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried it with export, but it won't work, i want to use my Class in my index.html, isn't that possible? Or shoul i interact with html in my ts class instead of importing the class in the html?

Comment: I don't think you can convert the JS inside html using Browserify alone. You may have to use a [plugin like this](https://github.com/shama/scriptify). Alternatively if you had set the class to `wiindow` object as I have shown above you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: But my idea is to develop javascript with TypeScript, and use it in my index.html just like JavaScript, what's the problem?
 why can't i use the compiled TypeScript, i don't understand, it's plain JavaScript just like other JS.
 Thank You!

Comment: If you see the generated JS you will understand. The class you created is not placed in global scope. It gets scoped within a module function.

Comment: Yes, i've seen it, it an anonymous function, isn't there a way to import that module? Or thell the compiler i won't modules? And use the class?